# Failed to load module pk-gtk-module

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat, putty, gtk

I am running RHEL6 and I am sshing into a linux server. Every time I open gvim or emacs, I get this error

```
$ gvim
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pk-gtk-module": libpk-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The error is harmless first couple of times but the third or fourth time, the computer screen freezes. I can move my mouse, but that's it. Nothing works and I have to restart again.

I have seen many solutions online which suggest installing gtk3 on my machine. I am running RHEL6 so that doesn't help me, as I would have to do a manual install and it is really hard to maintain it on the machine. I have also tried disabling libpk-gtk-module by using gconf-setting, but it still freezes. How can I stop my computer screen from freezing. I don't care about the error much. It just shows the font wrong in the x-session.

Edit1: I checked with the gnome-terminal and then ssh to the server, it doesn't hang the screen. It only happens with putty.

Comment: Contact your system administrator.

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton I added some more information. Could you please see if it is a know issue. I will contact my system admin

Comment: You said you were using RHEL 6. What is this about PuTTY?

Comment: I have RHEL6 on my laptop. I use putty on my laptop to ssh into the server

Comment: As far as I know you're the first person to actually try using the Linux version of PuTTY. I wouldn't expect it to work properly, being originally a Windows program.

Comment: haha. I am sorry. I just like putty from the windows world, so I use putty. It might just be a putty bug. Thanks for the help